# How could I run Golan application (backend) and ReactJS application (frontend) on the same domain to prevent CORS?

Tags: reactjs, go

So, I have a golang application and reactJs application. If I run them on the different domains, I get problems with CORS.

To allow CORS on the server side is not a problem at all, but I can't get cookies from the server, because they are ignored by browser as third-party cookies.

So, I see quite a simple solution - to run server and frontend on the same domain, but I can't understand, how to do that. How could I configure everything to run on the same domain without conflicts? What are the best practices to prevent CORS between golang app and ReactJS app?

Comment: What serves the reactjs app?

Comment: I'm serving it with Webpack

Comment: What webserver serves it? `webpack` is a bundler.

Comment: Well, let me tell you how I run it and on what domain, because question about server is a little bit confusing to me. I'm building a project with create-react-app, I've added the necessary code there, then I just run it on loaclhost:3000 by npm start script. The Golang backend app is running on docker container in VirtualBox

Comment: `npm start` is not a production ready solution. And in your case it's not even a development-friendly. You might have set up a nginx that forwards requests to both npm webserver and golang webserver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Go's file server to serve the static assets:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/api/", apiHandler)
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/var/www/my-app")))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil))
}

func apiHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {}
```

The documentation has [more examples for http.FileServer](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer).

Alternatively, you can use something like [github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata](https://godoc.org/github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata) (and go-bindata-assetfs) to compile your assets into the Go binary and serve them from memory.